# FFMPEG not expected results with blend=screen with 2 video overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i want 2 video overlay with the screen effect ( known in photoshop,  aftereffect,canvas etc)

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "blend=screen" output.mp4
```

but the lower layer becomes greyscale
[image]

what i want is the expected

PS 2 movie inputs dimensions are the same

Answer (score 0):

Add the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to use gbrp pixel format for each input, use `all_mode` [blend filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend-1) option, and then use the format filter again to output yuv420p pixel format for general MP4 playback compatibility:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=gbrp[fg];[1]format=gbrp[bg];[fg][bg]blend=all_mode=screen,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```